# GDB moves breakpoint to different line

Tags: c, gdb, msp430

I'm debugging C code running on a MSP430 microprocessor using GDB.

When I set a breakpoint on the line `double average = sum / 10;` using `break 172`, it confirms by responding `Breakpoint 1 at 0xc01c: file main.c, line 172`, but when I continue with `c`, the code runs until it hits `Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:184`.

I wasn't having issues debugging until recently, so I tried reverting everything to the previous version and I still have this issue. I have also tried:

- Turning my laptop off and on.
- Unplugging and re-plugging every cable related to the microprocessor and its circuit.
- Closing and re-opening all terminal windows.
- Re-compiling and re-loading my C code into the microprocessor.
- Print statements to help debugging aren't an option because the microprocessor can't hold `#include <stdio.h>`.
- Clearing all breakpoints present before setting this one, but none are found.

The code looks something like:

```
void main(void)
{
  OtherMethod();

  while(1)
  {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
          sum += i;
    }

    double average = sum / 10; // Line 172
  }  
}

void OtherMethod(void)
{    
  P1DIR |= LED1 + LED2; // Line 184
}
```

Other information that might be helpful is that I can successfully set a breakpoint on the line `sum += i;`.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Do you compile with optimization? Then try again without.

Comment: Compiling without optimization fixed the issue, if you post this as the answer I'll accept it. @thebusybee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile with optimization, several "strange" things *might* happen, see your compiler's documentation. This *might* lead to statements being removed or re-arranged, and when debugging, surprising behaviour.

To debug a program "by the line", compile without optimization.

Or live with the surprises; it's a source of delight, in any case.